# Outlook add-in appointment missing attributes when organizer

Tags: json, office-js

I'm working on an Outlook web add-in for the calendar, but I'm having some trouble with the Office.context.mailbox.item (appointment) I get when I'm the organizer of the appointment.

When I'm an attendee of the appointment I can see a lot of attributes on the Office.context.mailbox.item, but when I'm the organizer I can't even see the start or end times nor the attendees of the appointment.

I can get the start and end using getAsync on the object but should this even be necessary when they are available as attendee?

Why is this and how do I get as rich an object as organizer, as I do when attendee?

**UPDATE: item json added**

```
{
  "_data$p$0": {
    "_data$p$0": {
      "hostVersion": "16.0.8827.2148",
      "itemType": 5,
      "permissionLevel": 1,
      "userEmailAddress": "email@address.com",
      "userDisplayName": "firstname lastname",
      "userProfileType": "office365",
      "conversationId": null,
      "userTimeZone": "Romance Standard Time",
      "ewsUrl": "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx",
      "restUrl": "https://outlook.office.com/api",
      "userProfileCapabilities": { "SSO": false },
      "itemNumber": 3,
      "error": false
    },
    "_permissionLevel$p$0": 1
  },
  "_body$p$1": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that in Attendee Mode, Start/End is available as a property, whereas in Organizer Mode, Start/End must be obtained through getAsync. (https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox.item#end-datetime)

In general, in Compose/Organizer mode any property that can be changed by the user is available as a get/set pair, as the value could be changed and the add-in needs a way to get the updated value. In Read/Attendee mode, data is provided immediately as those values are not expected to change.

For example, if a new appointment is created...returning to the add-in the time of the appointment is probably not useful, as the user will change it soon. With a get/set, the Add-in can perform a Get, and get the live update when the add-in needs it, and then potentially call Set if need be.

As an aside, ideally there would be an event that is pushed to the add-in when those values change. We are aware of the need for Events, and they will be in a future API requirement set update, but I do not have a time frame to share yet.

Comment: I just updated my post with the Item I get before any get commands. So I should be able to retrieve all known attributes via getAsync? I believe that I tried with the dateTimeCreated attribute with no luck. Also I find it a bit odd that the item doesn't even have an ID at this point - it has already been sent to the attendees.

Comment: I see now according to the link you provided, that the attribute dateTimeCreated is only available in read-mode (which I assume means that you are in attendee-mode). I wonder why though... Why should an organizer not be able to retrieve the value for this attribute, not to change it but to read it?

Comment: EWSId can be tricky, when the item is a new item and has not been saved. (which is common when composing a *new* mail or appointment. We have SaveAsync to handle this, and that returns an EWSId. In theory the ID could be returned during the initial item if it has already been saved. (avoiding a call to saveAsync). For DateTimeCreated, it's just not there in compose mode. For both of these, we haven't heard much feedback for the need for these APIs. Feature Requests/Suggestions go through UserVoice at: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins.

Comment: I do realize that I'm on the composing form when I'm the organizer, but that the item doesn't have an ID and a created date when the appointment has already been sent out to the attendees (I'm opening it again after it has been sent) that doesn't make sense to me - shouldn't the fact that it is sent out trigger some kind of "save" functionality or is it totally legal to send out appointments that has no "home" seen from the organizer's point of view... What am I missing here?

Comment: You're not missing anything. Those values *could* be made accessible, but they currently are not, see the uservoice link if you think they should be added.

Comment: Suggestion added to user voice.